# Tkinter message box pops up before other actions

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I'm struggling with figuring out how to make the messagebox pop up at the right moment. It always seems to pop up before the window updates to show what I want it to. Here's an example; I want the button's text to update to 3 before the messagebox pops up, but it always updates after I click OK on the messagebox.

```
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import messagebox

 win = Tk()
 count = 0


 def click():
     global count
     count += 1
     btn.config(text=count)
     if count == 3:
         messagebox.showinfo('The count is 3')


 btn = Button(text='', command=click)
 btn.pack()

 win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried it and it updates as it is clicked. I can see the message window and the button showing 3. Are you saying yours still shows 2 when the message appears?

Comment: @nikost Yeah it shows 2 until after I click OK

Comment: It works fine in my Windows 10 running Python 3.10.2.

Comment: Not reproducible on windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your example code, I see the same behavior you describe.  I was able to work around it by adding a call to `win.update()` before the call to `messagebox.showinfo()`.  Full code below though I changed `count` from a primitive `int` to an `IntVar` which doesn't have any effect on your issue, I just wanted to see it if would:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def click():
    count.set(value := count.get() + 1)

    if value == 3:
        win.update()

        messagebox.showinfo(f"The count is {value}")

win = Tk()

count = IntVar(win, value=0)

Button(win, command=click, textvariable=count).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: tysm this fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to print on `messagebox.showinfo` in line 10 as above.

```
messagebox.showinfo(f"The count is", f"count {value}")
```

Output:

[image]